# Login Failed. PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo, authentication

Please help, i tried to make login system. Seems like no error, but when i tried to login using username and password it keep said that is invalid. Here is the code.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login` (
 `idlogin` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `nama` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `email` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `telepon` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
 `level` varchar(13) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

config.php

```
 ?php
session_start();

$DB_host = "localhost";
$DB_user = "root";
$DB_pass = "pwd";
$DB_name = "dataseminar";

try
{
     $DB_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_host};dbname={$DB_name}",$DB_user,$DB_pass);
     $DB_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
     echo $e->getMessage();
}
include_once 'class_user.php';
$user = new USER($DB_con);
?>
```

newlogin.php

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

if($user->is_loggedin()!="")
{
  $user->redirect('home.php');
}

if(isset($_POST['loginsbtn']))
{
   $username = $_POST['usrname'];
   $password = $_POST['pass'];

   if($user->login($username,$password))
   {
      $user->redirect('home.php');
   }
   else
   {
      $error = "Invalid username or password ";
   } 
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="menubarcss.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <style type="text/css">
    h1{
      font-family:Arial black;
      text-align: center;
      color:grey;
    }
    h3{
      font-family:Arial black;
      text-align: center;
      color:grey;
    }
  </style>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
  <body>
  <h1>APLIKASI PENGELOLA DATA SEMINAR DAN PELATIHAN</h1>
  <div class="container">
      <br/><br/><br/>
      <h2 align="center">Silahkan Login terlebih dahulu</h2>
       <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" align="center">
        <form method="post">
        <hr />
            <?php
            if(isset($error))
            {
                  ?>
                  <div class="alert alert-danger">
                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> &nbsp; <?php echo $error; ?> !
                  </div>
                  <?php
            }
            ?>
          <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="usrname" placeholder="Username" required></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" required></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" name="loginsbtn" value="LOGIN">
                    <input type="reset" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" name="clearbtn" value="CLEAR">
            </td>
          </tr>
          </form>
          <label>Belum punya akun ? <a href="createlogin.php">Sign Up</a></label>
        </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

class_user.php

```
<?php
class USER
{
    private $db;

    function __construct($DB_con)
    {
      $this->db = $DB_con;
    }

    public function register($username,$password,$nama,$email,$telepon,$level)
    {
       try
       {
           $new_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

           $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO LOGIN(username,password,nama,email,telepon,level) 
                                                       VALUES(:username, :password, :nama, :email, :telepon, :level)");

           $stmt->bindparam(":username", $username);
           $stmt->bindparam(":password", $new_password);
           $stmt->bindparam(":email", $email);
           $stmt->bindparam(":nama", $nama);
           $stmt->bindparam(":telepon", $telepon);
           $stmt->bindparam(":level", $level);            
           $stmt->execute(); 

           return $stmt; 
       }
       catch(PDOException $e)
       {
           echo $e->getMessage();
       }    
    }

    public function login($username,$password)
    {
       try
       {
          $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username=:username LIMIT 1");
          $stmt->execute(array(':username'=>$username));
          $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
          {
             if(password_verify($password, $userRow['password']))
             {
                $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['idLogin'];
                return true;
             }
             else
             {
                return false;
             }
          }
       }
       catch(PDOException $e)
       {
           echo $e->getMessage();
       }
   }

   public function is_loggedin()
   {
      if(isset($_SESSION['user_session']))
      {
         return true;
      }
   }

   public function redirect($url)
   {
       header("Location: $url");
   }

   public function logout()
   {
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['user_session']);
        return true;
   }
}
?>
```

It's been 3 days since i try to solve this problem. I will appreciate solution. Thank you.

Comment: and how have you tried debugging this? You have have numerous codepaths in your `login()` where it could return null which you're failing to take into account.

Comment: What debugging have you done? Is your `login` function being called? Is the SQL being generated properly? How many rows is your query returning? What part of the code is failing?

Comment: Thank you. I've found the answer for this problem. But now, a new problem comes up, it won't redirect to home.php. Any suggestion?

Comment: That should be a new question @TeddyMapandin

Comment: @JayBlanchard you mean i should create new question?

Comment: If you need the redirect problem solved, yes.

Comment: @TeddyMapandin 1) In your `is_loggedin()` method you only return TRUE if the user is logged in. But otherwise you don't return anything, so just put a `return FALSE;` after your if statement 2) After you have done the first point change your comparison from: `if($user->is_loggedin()!="")` to `if($user->is_loggedin() === FALSE)` to make sure if the user isn't logged in to redirect him.

Comment: @TeddyMapandin Also move your `return false;` in your `login()` method at the end of this method to return always false if it couldn't log you in. + Always put a `exit();` after each `header()` call to make sure your script stops executing

Comment: @Rizier123 i've tried u suggest but nothing happen. I know maybe it's a lot to ask, but have u tried my code?

Comment: @TeddyMapandin So your code works, just your `redirect()` method not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is because of this `varchar(30)` which is set for your password column.

```
`password` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
```

The length isn't long enough to accomodate the hash generated by `password_hash()`.

Alter your column to be `varchar(255)`

which is the reason why it's failing silently.

If I'm wrong about this, then it's playing a major role in this.

You should also make sure that no whitespace is included anywhere.

Plus, you may want to increase the lengths of some of your other columns.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

> *"Note that this constant is designed to change over time as new and stronger algorithms are added to PHP. For that reason, the length of the result from using this identifier can change over time. Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice)."*

```
$2y$10$.vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD98HNOgsNpDczlqm3Jq7KnEd1rVAGv3Fykk1a
                            ^ stops there at 30
```

Pulled from the manual:

```
/**
 * We just want to hash our password using the current DEFAULT algorithm.
 * This is presently BCRYPT, and will produce a 60 character result.
 *
 * Beware that DEFAULT may change over time, so you would want to prepare
 * By allowing your storage to expand past 60 characters (255 would be good)
 */
```

Plus, `bindparam` I have seen this fail many times with a lowercase "p". You may want to use `bindParam` with a capital "P".

Pay attention to the comments left under your question also.

Comment: Thank you, for password column size, that fix the problem. But now comes up new problem, it wont redirect to home.php. Any suggestion?

Comment: @TeddyMapandin You're welcome. *Hm...*, you may be outputting before header (add `exit;` after headers also, it's best). Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: thank you again for adding exit; but it doesn't change anything. still cant redirect. And i have tried add error reporting, still, no error shows up.

Comment: @TeddyMapandin You're welcome. It may have something to do with your USER class in not constructing other elements. I won't be able to help you out with this, since I am not good with classes. I know the basic principles of them, but can't say for certain on this. Try adding them in the constructor. Sorry, wish I could help out more on this.